# my tables size wont get back after i decrease browser window size

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, resize

i got a problem with responsive web design..so i added viewport and other stuff for having a responsive page to my page and when i resize my window and make it smaller my page works almost good but then when i resize again and increase window size. this time my second table does not get longer and stay in the same small size but also its position changes..can anyone help me plz...i put my code down here..it is a componenet for drawing graph using vis library.

```js
var nodes, edges, network;
var countid=0;
var removednodes = 0;
  
  
        // convenience method to stringify a JSON object
        function toJSON(obj) {
            return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4);
        }
        //this functions return a JSON object to show on console
        function consoleoutput(){
         for(i=0;i<=nodes.length+removednodes;++i){
   if(network.getConnectedNodes(i).length!=0){
          console.log("id = ",i);
          var connections = toJSON(network.getConnectedNodes(i));
          console.log("connections",connections);
   }
      }
        }
        function addNode() {    
  var x = document.getElementById("node-label").value;
  if (x == "") {
   alert("Label must be filled out");
   return false;
  }
     try {
    countid=countid+1;
                nodes.add({
                    id: countid,
                    label: document.getElementById('node-label').value,
                    color:document.getElementById('nodecolor').value
                });
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
   //checking if number of nodes is zero disable add edge button
   if(nodes.length<1)
    document.getElementById("edge-add").disabled = true;
   else
    document.getElementById("edge-add").disabled = false;
    
   //check if number of nodes is zero disable remove button 
   if(nodes.length<1)
    document.getElementById("edge-remove").disabled = true;
   else
    document.getElementById("edge-remove").disabled = false;
 
        }        
       
        function addEdge() {
   var x = document.getElementById("edge-from").value;
   if (x == "") {
    alert("form ID must be filled out");
    return false;
   }
   var y = document.getElementById("edge-to").value;
   if (y == "") {
    alert("to ID must be filled out");
    return false;
   }
            try {
                edges.add({
                    from: document.getElementById('edge-from').value,
                    to: document.getElementById('edge-to').value,
                    color:document.getElementById('edgecolor').value
                });
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        }
        function removeNode() {
            try {
                nodes.remove({id: document.getElementById('node-id').value});
    removednodes = removednodes+1;
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        }        
        function draw() {
            
            nodes = new vis.DataSet();
            nodes.on('*', function () {
                document.getElementById('nodes').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(nodes.get(), null, 4);
            });
            
           edges = new vis.DataSet();                        
           var container = 
     document.getElementById('network'); // container to render in

            var data = {
                nodes: nodes,
                edges: edges
            };
            var options = {};
            network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
   
   //check if number of nodes is zero disable add edge button
   if(nodes.length<1)
    document.getElementById("edge-add").disabled = true;
   else
    document.getElementById("edge-add").disabled = false;
    
   //check if number of nodes is zero disable remove button 
   if(nodes.length<1)
    document.getElementById("edge-remove").disabled = true;
   else
    document.getElementById("edge-remove").disabled = false;
            
        }
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }
     html, body {
            font: 11pt arial;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 150%;
            margin: 5px 0;
            font:;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 100%;
            margin: 5px 0;
        }
        table.view {
   max-width: 900px;
   display:inline-block;
   margin:auto;
        }  
        table td {
            /*vertical-align: top;*/
        }
        table table td {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        input[type=text], pre {
            border: 1px solid lightgray;
        }
        pre {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        #network {
   max-width:800px;
   height:400px;
   margin:auto;
            border: 1px solid lightgray;
            background: radial-gradient(circle, lightgrey , darkgrey); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
            border-radius: 15px;
   box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        }
        #nodes{
            border-radius: 15px;
   box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        }
  #main{
   max-height:600px;
   max-width:400px;
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:top;
   margin-right:40px;
   margin-top:40px;
   border:1px solid;
   border-radius:15px;
   box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  }
  #maintableh2{
   /*margin-left:100px;*/
   text-align: center;
   padding:0;
   width:100%;
  }
  #h2_view{
   /*margin-left:400px;*/
   text-align: center;
  }
  input{
   margin-left:0px;
  }
  label{
  width:25px;
  }
  input[type=text]:focus {
   border: 2px solid #555;
  }
  button:hover{
   box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  }
  table.functiontable{
   width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/master/dist/vis-network.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://visjs.org/dist/vis.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://visjs.org/dist/vis.js"></script>

  <body onload="draw();">
<div> 
  <table  id="main" style="background-color:lightgrey;">
   <tr>
    <td>
     <h2 id="maintableh2">Node</h2>
     <table class = "functiontable">                
      <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td><label for="node-label">Label</label></td>
       <td><input id="node-label" type="text" ></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td><label for="node-label">Color</label></td>
       <td><input type="color" id="nodecolor" value="#ff0000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td>
        <button id="node-add" onclick="addNode();">Add</button>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <h2 id="maintableh2">Edge</h2>
     <table class = "functiontable">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><label for="edge-from">From ID:</label></td>
        <td><input id="edge-from" type="text" ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td><label for="edge-to">To ID:</label></td>
       <td><input id="edge-to" type="text" ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td><label for="node-label">Color</label></td>
       <td><input type="color" id="edgecolor" value="#3377FF"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td>
        <button id="edge-add" onclick="addEdge();" >Add</button>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <h2 id="maintableh2">Remove</h2>
     <table class="functiontable">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><label >Node id</label></td>
        <td><input id="node-id" type="text" ></td>
      </tr>                
      <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td >
        <button id="edge-remove" onclick="removeNode();">Remove</button>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <button style="margin-top:30px" onclick="consoleoutput();">console</button>
    </td>
   </tr>

  </table>

  <table class="view">    
   <tr> 
    <td> 
     <h2  id="h2_view" >View</h2>
     <div id="network"></div>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <h2 id="h2_view">Nodes</h2>
     <pre id="nodes"></pre>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Does your HTML code contains this '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">' ?

Comment: yeah it has but thanks for answering

Comment: does vis provide a method to reflow its component? maybe it injects hard coded width value.
Have you set `autoResize` to `true` in the options of the `vis` object? The doc states there is a `redraw` method that you can call on the canvas.

Comment: yeah i use that but it doesnt work but still thanks for your time